# Refactor with some dynamic programming?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic, metaprogramming

I have a piece of code here that i really could use some help with refactoring. I need the different methods for adding relational data in a form in rails. The code is taken from http://railscasts.com/episodes/75-complex-forms-part-3, my problem is that i need to have the methods fro both the Material model and the Answer model. So i need the exact same code twice with "materials" replaced by "answers".

It seems this should be solved with some dynamic programming? But I have no experience at all with that.

How is this solved?

```
after_update :save_materials
after_update :save_answers  

def new_material_attributes=(material_attributes)
  material_attributes.each do |attributes|
    materials.build(attributes)
  end
end

def existing_material_attributes=(material_attributes)
  materials.reject(&:new_record?).each do |material|
    attributes = material_attributes[material.id.to_s]
    if attributes
      material.attributes = attributes
    else
      materials.delete(material)
    end
  end
end

def save_materials
  materials.each do |material|
    material.save(false)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might also want to take a look at this site:

http://refactormycode.com/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to have the same methods for `answers` as for `materials`, but duplicating the least code.   The way to do this is by abstracting some private methods that will work for either `answers` or `materials` and call them with the appropriate model from the methods specific to those models.  I've given a sample below.  Note that I didn't do anything with the `save_` methods because I felt they were short enough that abstracting them really didn't save much.

```
after_update :save_materials
after_update :save_answers  

// Public methods

def new_material_attributes=(material_attributes)
  self.new_with_attributes(materials, material_attributes)
end

def new_answer_attributes=(answer_attributes)
  self.new_with_attributes(answers, answer_attributes)
end

def existing_material_attributes=(material_attributes)
  self.existing_with_attributes(materials, material_attributes)
end

def existing_answer_attributes=(answer_attributes)
  self.existing_with_attributes(answers, answer_attributes)
end

def save_materials
  materials.each do |material|
    material.save(false)
  end
end

def save_answers
  answers.each do |answer|
     answer.save(false)
  end
end

// Private methods    

private
def new_with_atttributes(thing,attributes)
    attributes.each do |attribute|
       thing.build(attribute)
    end
end

def existing_with_attributes=(things, attributes)
  things.reject(&:new_record?).each do |thing|
    attrs = attributes[thing.id.to_s]
    if attrs
      thing.attributes = attrs
    else
      things.delete(thing)
    end
  end
end
```